# system call return values and errno

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls, systems-programming

I am using following system calls in my program:

```
recvfrom
sendto
sendmsg
```

And from each system call mentioned above I check if it completes with out any interruption and in case if it is interrupted, I retry.

Ex:

```
recvagain:     
    len = recvfrom(fd, response, MSGSIZE, MSG_WAITALL, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &fromlen);
    if (errno == EINTR) {
           syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "recvfrom interrupted: %s", strerror(errno));
           goto recvagain;
    }
```

Problem here is that do I need to reset errno value to 0 each and every time it fails. Or if recvfrom() is successful, does it reset errno to 0?

recvfrom() man page says:

> Upon successful completion, recvfrom() returns the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the
>   peer has performed an orderly shutdown, recvfrom() returns 0.
>   Otherwise the function returns -1 and sets errno to indicate the
>   error.

same case with sendto and sendmsg.

I can n't really check this now as I don't have access to server-client setup.
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `errno` pseudo "variable" may not change on successful syscalls. So you could clear it either before your `recvfrom`, or when `len<0` and having tested its value.

See [errno(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) man page for more.

Actually, as Robert Xiao (nneonneo) commented, you should not write `errno` and just test it when the syscall has failed (in that case, the C function -e.g. `recvfrom` etc...- wrapping that syscall would have written `errno` before returning -1).

Comment: You rarely need to clear `errno`; I don't think this is one of those times.

Comment: The man reason for clearing `errno` is to cover the case when it was previously set (some time ago) by an unrelated syscall.

Comment: You normally shouldn't care. As I indicated in my answer, the correct solution is to check `len` to see if an error actually occurred.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But it’s normally not needed, because you should _always_ check the return value _before_ looking at errno. It is only necessary when calling functions in which the value indicating an error condition (e.g. -1 for getpriority(2), or NULL for readdir(3)) is also a valid response from the function (nice value -1 or end of directory stream, respectively).

Answer (score 7):

`recvfrom` returns `-1` if it is interrupted (and sets `errno` to `EINTR`). Therefore, you should just check `len`:

```
if(len == -1) {
    if(errno == EINTR) {
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE, "recvfrom interrupted");
        goto recvagain;
    } else {
        /* some other error occurred... */
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I ll do that and what about errno? you mean to say that it does n't get reset if system call is successful, am I correct?

Comment: `errno` can only be trusted if the function returned a value indicating an error. Otherwise, it could be meaningless.